# Is there any way to make Sublime Text 2 to auto complete structure children in C?

Tags: c, autocomplete, sublimetext2, ctags, cscope

For example, I have a header file , a.h

```
struct f
{
    int aaaa;
    int bbbb;
    int cccc;
};
```

And a C file, a.c

```
#include "a.h"

int abcd;
void main()
{
    struct f abcd;
    abcd.a
}
```

What i want is, when i type abcd.a, i hope it will automatically pop up aaaa, not abcd.

I know there need to be a C parser to do it, but i'm already using Cscope and Ctags, Is there anything to do what i want by reading Cscope database?Or any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [SublimeClang](https://github.com/quarnster/SublimeClang) and it should provide auto complete for you.

Comment: But it's not continued